# Meaning of "OK pues"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I've heard "OK pues" in hispanoamerican TV.

Is this similar in nuance to saying in English, "OK then," to suggest that an agreement has been reached or a meeting is about to conclude (i.e., "I think we're done here"), etc.?

Comment: You're right, that's it.

Comment: It could be that, or it could be more vague, since "pues" is a common filler word that doesn't necessarily convey meaning.  If you think about it, "okay" in English could suggest that an agreement has been reached, but it might also be used as a filler.

Comment: @aparente001, your point about filler words is interesting and leads me to think that I might have asked instead if the "pues" adds a suggestion of finality.

Comment: I think that it does, definitely, add a *suggestion* of finality.  But I personally wouldn't want to rely on whatever was said without some more clarification.  (That's just my personal opinion.)

Comment: @aparente001 hey I was browsing through unanswered questions and found this one. Would you want to post an answer with what you explained in comments? Thanks!

Comment: @fedorqui - good idea, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be "alright then," or it could be more vague, since "pues" is a common filler word that doesn't necessarily convey meaning. If you think about it, "okay" in English could suggest that an agreement has been reached, but it might also be used as a filler.

It might indicate finality, but I wouldn't rely on it without some more clarification.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different contexts to define ''Ok pues'':

1. If you're talking with someone and that person gives you an opinion of something and you want to give your opinion too.  So as not to be rude, after her/his opinion you could say ''Ok, pues, yo pienso que...'' That could be translated like ''In my opinion" or "I think that in another way''.
2. The second way is when you want to finish a conversation in a more rude way. You don't want to talk with that person or you want to talk about another topic. 
   It's a kind of rude way to finish a conversation without the acceptance of the other person.

Answer (score 2):

> Ok pues = Alright then.

As mentioned above, *pues* is a filler word that changes a bit depending on context.